# ASP.NET Core 3.1, get the controller and action name from referrer url in the current HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to get the routedata information, specifically controller and action name for the current reqests referrer url.
I am using the endpoint routing feature. I read somewhere IRouter is not applicable if endpoint routing feature is enabled.

```
//var router = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IRouter>();
//router is null, since i used UseEndpoints routing i guess
Uri urlReferrer = context.HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer;
if (urlReferrer != null)
{
    var requestFeature = new HttpRequestFeature()
    {
        Method = "GET",
        PathBase = string.Empty,
        Path = urlReferrer.AbsoluteUri,
        QueryString = urlReferrer.Query
    };
    var features = new FeatureCollection();
    features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(requestFeature);
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(features);
    var ep = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
    //ep is null since the context is not passed through routing, i guess
    //how do i pass this httpcontext though routing middleware to get the route values

    //tried RouteAsync but IRouter is null
    //var routeContext = new RouteContext(httpContext);
    //context.RouteData.Routers.Add(router);
    //await router.RouteAsync(routeContext);

    var reffererActionName = httpContext.GetRouteData().Values["action"].ToString();
    var reffererControllerName = httpContext.GetRouteData().Values["controller"].ToString();
    //i need the action+controller name for the referrer url    
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider sp)
{
    ...

    app.UseRouting();

    ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Landing}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        //endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Any pointer or idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this code? In a custom middleware?

Comment: Never trust 'referrer' for anything.

Comment: So you want to parse the referrer url and turn it into an endpoint? The EndpointDataSource service defines the routes. EndpointRoutingMiddleware uses a MatcherFactory service to compile a state machine for matching routes.  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/src/EndpointRoutingMiddleware.cs It seems complicated to reuse this infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are writing this code but here's a .NET 6 application that shows how to get access to the endpoint and the `ControllerActionDescriptor` from a custom middleware:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var controllerActionDescriptor = context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();

    if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
    {
        // Get the controller information here
    }

    return next(context);
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/")]
    public string Get() => "Hello World";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#url-matching-1) related with Routing,and in the doc it has been mentioned：

When a routing middleware executes, it sets an Endpoint and route values to a request feature on the HttpContext from the current request:

Calling HttpContext.GetEndpoint gets the endpoint.

HttpRequest.RouteValues gets the collection of route values.

You could try

```
HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
```

and

```
HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
```

If you have further issue on the case，please show us more details